# typescript / .Net Core : downloaded jpg/png file format not supported

Tags: javascript, typescript, .net-core, vuejs3, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm having difficulty viewing downloaded png/jpg files, the file downloads properly but cannot be viewed. I think it could be related to the way I'm saving the object in typescript or something to do with content header types?

Backend: .Net Core 6.0 Web API

Frontend: Vue 3

This is the result of trying to open the downloaded image:

[image]

Fiddler trace shows the image being sent from the server:
[image]

This is how I'm downloading the file in TS:

```
await someService
.download(item.url, item.name)
.then(async (r: any) => {
  const blob = new Blob([r.data]);
  const link = document.createElement("a");
  link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const disposition = r.request.getResponseHeader("Content-Disposition");
  if (disposition && disposition.indexOf("attachment") !== -1) {
    const filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
    let matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
    if (matches != null && matches[1]) {
      link.download = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, "");
    }
  }
  link.click();
  URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);
})
.catch((err: any) => {
  showError(err);
});
```

This is how the server sends its response:

```
public IActionResult DownloadAttachmentAsync([FromQuery] DownloadAttachmentInputDto model)
{
    try
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(_pathToFile, FileMode.Open);
        return File(fs, "image/png", model.FileName);
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        _errorHandler.Error(_loggedInUser, err);
        return BadRequest(_errorHandler.UserFriendlyErrorMessage(err));
    }
}
```

sample response header (different file):

[image]

Not sure where else to look, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I've tried downloading other files types (e.g. text/pdf/zip) and they are download without issues

Comment: The server response says: `Content-Type: application/octet-stream`. So the server is saying that the content is a generic file to be downloaded, not an image. I think maybe this is causing the problem. View [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20509354/18789859) for more detail about this.

Comment: Updated question... Unfortunately, that did not help, and again, fiddler shows the content perfectly. In this case I made sure it was a png extension (and set type to image/png). Really appreciate the help, been stuck for days and still don't know where to look!

Comment: "This is the result of trying to open the downloaded image" , what are you actually trying to open the image with?

Comment: Multiple image editing software.. MS Paint .. the image is from the Windows 10 built into PhotoViewer.. but I tried Paint, Adobe.. even downloaded it on a different machine just in case.

Comment: could you check if [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68832895/7006384) helps. `responseType` is important when you are handling pdf, image type of files.

Comment: Probably returning `FileContentResult` instead of `File` helps. Or using [Produces(MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet)] as decorator.

Also, as pointed out before, in case you use Axios, please set the responseType to "blob" in the GET request. URL.createObjectURL should be able to consume the result directly

Comment: Gents, I cannot thank you enough for your help, I finally had the chance to review the comments... issue was the missing responseType! @A.Z you had the suggestion first, bounty is yours. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles upon similar type of issue.

Whenever you want to download `pdf/image` type of documents in frontend its necessary to define `responseType:blob` for your api call.

I have explained it in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67983200/download-file-from-backend-laravel-using-vue-as-frontend/68832895#68832895)